# Advantages of using Grails environment specific configuration

Tags: grails

I'm moving to Grails from traditional Spring and I'm confused on the logic behind [Grails per environment](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#environments) configuration files. I've usually seen environment aware code as an anti-pattern. What are the reasons for having a single config file that specifies the configuration for all environments as opposed to having a different configuration file for each environment?

What I've seen is that with this Grails *per environment* approach each environment has the same configuration file but at run-time you must tell the app what environment it belongs to. This has lead to code that behaves one way in prod and another in test.

```
if(Environment == TEST){
//do something
}
if(Environment == PROD){
//do something that wasn't tested
}
```

Is any one using this and if so why not just one distinct configuration per environment so instead of

```
dataSource {
    pooled = false
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb"
        }
    }
}
```

You would have just:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = false
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = "Environment-Specific-Password"
    dbCreate = "create-drop"
    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb"
}
```

Then if there is something you don't want to run in test, in the configuration file sitting in the test environment, disable that feature. To re-iterate my question, what are the advantages, if any, to explicitly making the application environment aware, isn't this a well known bad idea? A little surprised its in the Grails framework.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have quite a few questions here, but at the root of the issue is your question "Why have environment specific configuration settings in one file?"

Simply put, because it keeps all the configuration in one file, for all environments. For example, you may use a different SMTP server for development/testing/production. Instead of making the code figure that out it just uses whatever value is defined in the configuration. Keeping that one setting for all the various environments in a single file allows you to see what it is easily and uniformly.

You don't have to use one per environment if you don't need. You can use one that is applied regardless of the environment.

The single file avoids having multiple files to maintain or determine which one to load at run time. It's all in one place.

I agree, having code that is environment specific is a horrible idea and should be avoided. Configuration values should be used (as stated above) instead.